# Is (int&&)5 an integral constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference

g++ accepts the code:

```
char b[static_cast<int&&>(5)];
```

N3936 [expr.const]/3 defines the term as:

> An integral constant expression is an expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type, implicitly converted to a prvalue, where the converted expression is a core constant expression. [Note: Such expressions
>   may be used as array bounds [...]

I'm unsure because the expression looks like it has type `int&&`  but the definition of *integral type* in 3.9 doesn't make any mention of reference types.

In case it was unclear, my question is: Is `static_cast<int&&>(5)` an integral constant expression?

---

*Background:* The question is motivated by the following example:

```
char *c = (1 - 1);
char *d = static_cast<int&&>(0);
```

All recent versions of `g++` with `-std=c++11` accept the `c` line but reject the `d` line.  The C++11 standard said that a null pointer constant is an *integral constant expression with value `0`* . (This was changed for C++14).

clang (3.4.1 and later) rejects the `c` line in `-std=c++11` mode.

So it appears there is a bug in g++, but I'd like to confirm whether the bug is in the `b` or the `d` definition.

Comment: The type of an expression is never a reference type. It is always either an object type or `void`.

Comment: No, I have no idea. I just wanted to point out that you made an incorrect statement in the question.

Comment: "clang (3.4.1 and later) incorrectly rejects the c line in -std=c++11 mode." Nope, that change's a [DR](http://wg21.link/cwg903).

Comment: @T.C. how far back in time do DRs go? Just the previous published standard, or all standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell `static_cast<int&&>(5)` is indeed a constant expression the result of this is an *xvalue* from the draft C++11 standard section `5.2.9` [expr.static.cast]:

> [...]if T is an rvalue
>   reference to object type, the result is an xvalue[...]

and if we then go to section `5.19` [expr.const] we have:

> A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless[...]

and we have the following bullet:

> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to

with the following exception:

> - a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile temporary object whose lifetime has not
>     ended, initialized with a constant expression;

You also noted:

> clang (3.4.1 and later) incorrectly rejects the c line in -std=c++11 mode.

but as T.C. noted since this change was applied via [DR 903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903) clangs behavior is valid.